# Empty/blank form window in C# Empty Project (.Net)

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, controls, drawing

I need some help cause I don't know what's wrong with my new project!

I stared a new **Empty Project (.NET)** in VS 2019, added same references to create form and draw different controls on it like buttons, labels and so on... Everything looks good for me and I don't get any warning/error. When I run my project it shows the form how I expected, but it's empty... no buttons or labels on the form, only the whitish coloured blank window [see picture].

I'm not familiar with the empty projects, so probably I missed something.. I tried to type *"InitializeComponent()"* to the class constructor but I got an error *"Error CS0103 The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context"..* I don't use the designer as this is an empty project and it's not come with it (and I don't need it!), so I suppose I don't need this method?

Here's the code and pictures to help localize the issue.. Probably just a noob mistake somewhere but I can't figure it out..
Please help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FileManager
{
    class EntryPoint
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Manager manager = new Manager();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace FileManager
{
    public class Manager
    {
        public Form WindowMain { get; set; }
        public ListView ViewArea { get; set; }
        public ImageList IconList { get; set; }
        public Button Back_btn { get; set; }
        public TextBox Path_tbx { get; set; }
        public Label FileNameTxt_lbl { get; set; }

        public Manager()
        {
            //InitializeComponent(); << Drop Error CS0103

            WindowMain = new Form
            {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable,
                Size = new Size(960, 540),
                Text = "FileManager"
            };

            ViewArea = new ListView
            {
                SmallImageList = IconList,
                LargeImageList = IconList,
                View = View.LargeIcon
            };

            IconList = new ImageList
            {
                ImageSize = new Size(48, 48),
                ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
            };

            Back_btn = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(100, 100),
                Text = "Back"
            };

            FileNameTxt_lbl = new Label
            {
                Text = "File Name:"
            };

            Application.Run(WindowMain);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution of my issue! It was quite simple to display the controls on my form... I should have add each of my control (buttons etc..) to the control collection of my form object (WindowMain), so simple!

Here's my fixed code:

```
namespace FileManager
{
    public class Manager
    {
        public Form WindowMain { get; set; }
        public ListView ViewArea { get; set; }
        public ImageList IconList { get; set; }
        public Button Back_btn { get; set; }
        public TextBox Path_tbx { get; set; }
        public Label FileNameTxt_lbl { get; set; }

        public Manager()
        {
            WindowMain = new Form
            {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable,
                Size = new Size(960, 540),
                Text = "FileManager"
            };

            ViewArea = new ListView
            {
                SmallImageList = IconList,
                LargeImageList = IconList,
                View = View.LargeIcon
            };

            IconList = new ImageList
            {
                ImageSize = new Size(48, 48),
                ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
            };

            Back_btn = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(100, 100),
                Text = "Back"
            };

            FileNameTxt_lbl = new Label
            {
                Text = "File Name:"
            };
            
            // These lines need to fix:
            WindowMain.Controls.Add(ViewArea);
            WindowMain.Controls.Add(Back_btn);
            WindowMain.Controls.Add(FileNameTxt_lbl);

            Application.Run(WindowMain);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a Windows Forms Application instead of an Empty project. It will be much easier to learn by sample.

**InitializeComponent** is a required method. Please check the auto-generated file with comments:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Text = "Form1";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then InitializeComponent has to be called in the constructor like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already used WinForm applications and I don't like it.. I like to do everything via code. Also the winform adds many thing to the project by default.. I know if a complex app with a lot of control element the case, the winform project is the good choice as faster to design it visually.

Comment: WPF is better option if you like to have more manual control over the UI.

Comment: Yes you're right! I will learn WPF after that I finished this little file manager prototype. Probably I will make a modern visual for it with WPF. Btw I found a solution which don't need InitializeComponent method to use. Looks this is the simplest way to do!